# What is the correct way to convert observer to octane version of ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-octane

I was trying to convert all my ember-component into OCTANE version. But I got a bigger doubt. How can I convert the `observer` code into an OCTANE version? For example,

```
parent.hbs
 
 <Child @value={{this.value}} />

child.hbs

 <div>{{this.newUpdate}}</div>

child.js

  export default class ChildComponent extends Component {     
      /** Previous code: sample code only
        valueUpdate: observer('value', function() {
            this.newValue = this.value / 12 * 2;
        })
      */
  }
```

How can I update the observer into octane way? Any idea please...

***Note:*** I tried using '@observer' but it didn't work inside the component.

Answer (score 5):

Ember Octane follows another programming model in that regard. Instead of observing a property and updating another one whenever it changes, you should use a native getter to derive state.

```js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';

export default class ChildComponent extends Component {
  // I assume that value is a local state of this component.
  // If it's an argument passed to the component on invocation.
  // You don't need to declare it here but can reference
  // this.args.value directly in the getter.
  @tracked value;

  get newValue() {
    return this.value / 12 * 2;
  }
}
```

As long as the value is derived from a tracked property the template will rerender whenever it changes. No need to manually update a value using an observer or explicitly list dependency as you needed to do with computed properties.

Arguments passed to components are autotracked. So in case `value` is not a local state but passed in as an argument, it's as simple as:

```js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';

export default class ChildComponent extends Component {
  get newValue() {
    return this.args.value / 12 * 2;
  }
}
```